# How do I keep track of multiple heartbeats in Drools?

Tags: drools

I have a scenario in which I receive heartbeats from multiple sources, and need to use Drools to keep track of them. I do *not* know how many sources I'll be dealing with ahead of time, and new sources can be introduced at any time (could be hundreds). A heartbeat object contains attributes indicating the source of the heartbeat (a `String`) and the rate at which heartbeats from that source should be arriving (an `int`, in seconds). The heartbeat rate can also change for a given source. I would need to keep track of all known sources, their heartbeat rates, handle new sources, and perform action(s) when any given heartbeat expires and/or when a heartbeat does not come in as expected.

I am aware of the heartbeat syntax example in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#cep-negative-patterns_decision-engine) but to my understanding this doesn't support variables (i.e. I can't use a variable in the `after` statement). I have been looking at [temporal operators](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#cep-temporal-operators_decision-engine), [entry points](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#cep-event-streams-proc_decision-engine), `@timestamp` and `@expires` tags, and other potentially relevant features, but have yet to find a solution.

I know Drools is capable of many things, and maybe I don't quite see things from a "rules engine" way of thinking, but I am really at a loss as to how this could be done. If anyone can provide some insight, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key part that you're misunderstanding is that the "heartbeat" in the documentation isn't something built into Drools -- it's an example that they're using to illustrate a simple use case. The class that represents your heartbeat can be as you define it, so your application's heartbeats can vary their models as you need them.

That means that you can define the model for your heartbeat to be whatever you want. A simple way to solve your problem would be to include a field in the class called `source` which indicates where your heartbeat is coming from. Then you can add a restriction on your rule criteria to limit the rule to specific source/s.

So, for example:

```
class MyHeartbeat {
  private String source;
  // other fields as needed/appropriate
  // getters and setters
}
```

And then you could write rules like:

```
import com.example.MyHeartbeat

declare MyHeartbeat
  @role( event )
end

rule "Trigger for event from source A"
when
  $h: MyHeartbeat(source == "A") from entry-point "MonitoringStream"
  not(MyHeartbeat(this != $h, this after[0s,10s] $h, source == "A") from entry-point "MonitoringStream")
then
  // Do something for this Event from source A
end

rule "Trigger for event from source B, C or D"
when
  $h: MyHeartbeat(source in ("B", "C", "D")) from entry-point "MonitoringStream"
  not(MyHeartbeat(this != $h, this after[0s,10s] $h, source in ("B", "C", "D")) from entry-point "MonitoringStream")
then
  // Do something for event from source B/C/D
end
```

You will note that this rule is pretty much a copy-paste from the documentation, except using the heartbeat class I defined.

If you had a discrete set of sources you could go the route of having multiple entry-points -- eg one for each source. But as you mention you may have any arbitrary number of them which doesn't make defining discrete entry-points a valid workflow for you since that would require a lot of overhead and maintenance.

Comment: I have been trying to do something like this, but note that (a) I don't know ahead of time what "source" will send me a heartbeat, so I can't do e.g. `source == "A"` and (b) your example uses a fixed 10s interval, when in my scenario each individual source could have a different interval (i.e. the `MyHeartbeat` class would have a `private int rate` attribute) yet I can't have variables in the `after` statement

Comment: My example is, as I mentioned, a copy-paste from the documentation. Your question is about custom heartbeats, not about the rules. So I used the stock rules.

Comment: You might want to consider having groups or "classes" of heart-beats rather then making them source specific. For example, a set of "Critical" heart beats which use 10 second intervals -- you can use a "type" enum on your model and then go from there. In a world of IoT devices, you could have a set of rules that applies to all thermostats, another set that applies to clothes washers and dryers. etc. The point I was making was that the event sent by your application/device is limited only by your imagination. You'll need to consider your specific application to design it appropriately.

Comment: Having them source-specific is not something I have any control over. I already knew how to create a heartbeat object; that was not the issue. I was also already aware of the heartbeat example from the documentation. In my particular case, however, it may not be usable. The issue, specifically, is that I have yet to figure out the rule(s) I need to keep track of these heartbeats (identify new ones, reset timers as they come in, actions on expiry, etc). The inability of temporal operators to accept variables seems to be a hindrance; I don't know how else I would do it

Comment: ... i literally just said don't make them source specific. Why can't you do something like a type/group/class (in the plain English sense, not the Java sense)/etc sorting?

Comment: Because the messages my app receives (and must be added to Drools) have a standardized, defined structure that I must support. There are no "types" here. Just an _n_ number of external entities (sources) sending heartbeats, that I must capture and track as I defined above. Hardcoding the heartbeat intervals in the `after` statement simply won't work